# AF_UNIX socket overhead?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I'm seeing a couple strange things with a pair of AF_UNIX sockets created by a call such as:

```
 socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sfd);
```

Where sfd is an int[2] array for the file descriptors.

First, the default buffer size seems to be exactly 122K (124928 bytes), rather than anything from /proc/sys/net (such as wmem_default which is set to 128K).  Does anyone know the cause of this strange buffer size?

Second, when writing small messages through the socket (8 bytes).  I can only write 423 of them before the write blocks, which is only 8*423 = 3384 bytes, another odd size.  The messages are acting as though they're taking up 295 + a little bytes each.  What's the source of this overhead?

Running on RHEL6 (2.6.32, 64-bit)

I wrote a program to try different sizes of data to compare overhead costs:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define DATA_SIZE 4

void run(size_t size) {
    int sfd[2];
    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sfd) == -1) {
        perror("error");
    }


    int sndbuf, sbsize = sizeof(sndbuf);
    getsockopt(sfd[0], SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sndbuf, (socklen_t*)&sbsize);

    printf("Data Size: %zd\n", size);
    char buff[size];   
    size_t wrote=0;
    for (size_t ii=0; ii < 32768; ii++) {
        if ((send(sfd[0], buff, size, MSG_DONTWAIT) == -1) && (errno == EAGAIN)) {
            wrote = ii;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Wrote:     %zd\n", wrote);

    if (wrote != 0) { 
        int bpm = sndbuf/wrote;
        int oh  = bpm - size;

        printf("Bytes/msg: %i\n",  bpm);
        printf("Overhead:  %i\n",  oh);
        printf("\n");
    }

    close(sfd[0]); close(sfd[1]);
}

int main() {
    int sfd[2];
    socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sfd);

    int sndbuf, sbsize = sizeof(sndbuf);
    getsockopt(sfd[0], SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sndbuf, (socklen_t*)&sbsize);

    printf("Buffer Size: %i\n\n", sndbuf);
    close(sfd[0]); close(sfd[1]);

    for (size_t ii=4; ii <= 4096; ii *= 2) {
        run(ii);
    }
}
```

Which gives:

```
Buffer Size: 124928

Data Size: 4
Wrote:     423
Bytes/msg: 295
Overhead:  291

Data Size: 8
Wrote:     423
Bytes/msg: 295
Overhead:  287

Data Size: 16
Wrote:     423
Bytes/msg: 295
Overhead:  279

Data Size: 32
Wrote:     423
Bytes/msg: 295
Overhead:  263

Data Size: 64
Wrote:     423
Bytes/msg: 295
Overhead:  231

Data Size: 128
Wrote:     348
Bytes/msg: 358
Overhead:  230

Data Size: 256
Wrote:     256
Bytes/msg: 488
Overhead:  232

Data Size: 512
Wrote:     168
Bytes/msg: 743
Overhead:  231

Data Size: 1024
Wrote:     100
Bytes/msg: 1249
Overhead:  225

Data Size: 2048
Wrote:     55
Bytes/msg: 2271
Overhead:  223

Data Size: 4096
Wrote:     29
Bytes/msg: 4307
Overhead:  211
```

Versus using a pipe there's definitely a lot of overhead:

```
Data Size: 4
Wrote:     16384
Bytes/msg: 4
Overhead:  0

Data Size: 8
Wrote:     8192
Bytes/msg: 8
Overhead:  0

Data Size: 16
Wrote:     4096
Bytes/msg: 16
Overhead:  0

Data Size: 32
Wrote:     2048
Bytes/msg: 32
Overhead:  0

Data Size: 64
Wrote:     1024
Bytes/msg: 64
Overhead:  0

Data Size: 128
Wrote:     512
Bytes/msg: 128
Overhead:  0

Data Size: 256
Wrote:     256
Bytes/msg: 256
Overhead:  0

Data Size: 512
Wrote:     128
Bytes/msg: 512
Overhead:  0

Data Size: 1024
Wrote:     64
Bytes/msg: 1024
Overhead:  0

Data Size: 2048
Wrote:     32
Bytes/msg: 2048
Overhead:  0

Data Size: 4096
Wrote:     16
Bytes/msg: 4096
Overhead:  0
```

Comment: send() returns the number of bytes actually written. You should be totalling these, not just assuming it was all written.

Comment: Worst case I'll have written less than what I'm claiming, which would make the overhead on the domain socket even worse.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the socket(7) man page. There is a section that reads:

> SO_SNDBUF
>                 Sets or gets the maximum socket send buffer in bytes.  The kernel doubles  this  value
>                 (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead) when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this
>                 doubled value is  returned  by  getsockopt(2).   The  default  value  is  set  by  the
>                 /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default  file  and  the  maximum  allowed  value is set by the
>                 /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max file.  The minimum (doubled)  value  for  this  option  is
>                 2048.

So it appears that the overhead is simply to hold bookkeeping information for the Kernel.

Comment: I'm not even sure that applies to the local sockets, and a simple halving of the available buffer space still wouldn't account for all the overhead I'm seeing.

Comment: The man page doesn't distinguish between AF_UNIX or the non local domains so I'm assuming it applies across the board. That's all the documentation I've been able to find regarding the situation. I suspect if you need to know "exactly" what the overhead is used for you will have to take a look at the kernel networking code.

Comment: I haven't accepted this answer because I think even with the factor-of-two overhead, I'm still seeing way too much per-message.  Even if the kernel was only letting me use 62464 bytes, then I should be able to write 15000+ messages before filling the buffer, and I'm only seeing 1/30 of that.

Comment: You will need to read the Kernel networking code to get all the details of what is done with the overhead as I mentioned before. I'm just pointing out what the man pages say about overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the value of the `net.unix.max_dgram_qlen` sysctl?

The kernel imposes a limit on the maximum number of in-flight AF_UNIX datagrams.
On my system the limit is actually very low: only 10.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, no.  Would that apply here though, since I'm u sing a SOCK_STREAM type?

Comment: No, that should only apply to datagram sockets, at least on the kernel version I'm looking at.

Comment: In fact, I can't see why a unix datagram socket write would ever short if hitting wmem_max.

Comment: I can say that increasing `net.unix.max_dgram_qlen` doesn't change the overhead. My system has a default value of 10, I change it to 200 without any change in the programs output or calculated overhead.

Comment: Not so much wrong as besides the point. Still, you're right. Please stop upvoting me ;)