# Default protocol for AF_UNIX sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, networking

I'm curious what the default protocol is for an AF_UNIX SOCK_STREAM socket.  I'm trying to track down exactly what the packet overhead should be, but I can't figure out what protocol is used by default.  I suspect it's *not* IPPROTO_TCP because this:

```
socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sfd)
```

works while, this:

```
socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, sfd)
```

Gives a "Protocol not supported error".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since an **AF_UNIX** unix socket is a local thing, there's no such thing as added protocol overhead in this case. You can use it in **SOCK_STREAM** or **SOCK_DGRAM** mode to make it connection-oriented or connectionless, respectively, but that's all: no protocol headers are added and it traverses none of the network or transport protocol implementations in the network stack.

Comment: This relates to another post I made [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899814/af-unix-socket-overhead) in which I am seeing a significant amount of overhead sending data through AF_UNIX pipes (betwee 200 and 300 bytes it would seem).  So if there's no protocol headers I'm very confused.

Comment: There is some overhead inside the kernel when data is copied between the source and destination sockets, though it's not a protocol overhead per se. Inside the kernel this copying is optimized somewhat to make skb memory allocation not hog too much memory, see e.g. net/unix/af_unix.c unix_stream_sendmsg().

Comment: I have a pretty passing familiarity with kernel land, so the unix_stream_sendmsg() is a little beyond me, but I can't imagine there's 200+ bytes of overhead is there?  That's what I'm seeing.

Comment: If I use a pipe I can push exactly the amount of data I think I should be able to, so the unix domain sockets are definitely adding some sort of overhead...

Answer (score 4):

**AF** stands for **A** ddress **F** amily whereas **PF** stands for **P** rotocol **F** amily.

The **AF_UNIX** family does not have a protocol IPPROTO_TCP that is supported by that address family. AF_UNIX is for interprocess communications between processes on the same system in the UNIX® domain. **The AF_UNIX and AF_UNIX_CCSID address family supports a protocol of 0 for both SOCK_STREAM and SOCK_DGRAM.**

Read more here: [Sockets](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/socket.htm)

Comment: I know they support protocol 0, but as far as I know that just tells it to use the default, I'm curious what that default is.

Comment: @gct: The protocol is AF_UNIX, which means it is using interprocess communication via a file to communicate. The protocol name is PF_UNIX.

Answer (score 2):

The only valid "protocol" when using AF_UNIX is zero.

Look at [socket(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html) and [unix(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html)